# where is my php installation path

Tags: centos, centos5

I am using centos and I need to find out where is the php installation path is. Is there a command I can use to find that out.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new test.php files and inserting this code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then browse to test.php in a browser.  This should give you a lot of information on php.

If you installed via an rpm also try

```
 rpm -ql php
```

or

```
 find / -name php.ini
```

Comment: insert what code? I don't see anything.

Comment: sorry, forgot to code mark my php, fixed in post.

Comment: The real answer comes in second: phpinfo is not useful in this case. rpm -ql php, by its turn, lists what you are looking for!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you mean by install path, if you're talking about the binary 'which php' will probably work.

If you're referring to something else like the extension install dir and assuming your php was installed with RPMs, do a 'yum install php-devel' to get the php-config command. You can run it with no options to get a listing of everything it knows or you can request only certain info from it, here's some useful ones for your situation:

```
php-config --php-binary
php-config --extension-dir
php-config --include-dir
```

Also try running 'php -i' on the command line to get the output of phpinfo.

Answer (score 4):

I believe best answer should be using linux shell command:

```
whereis php
```

Comment: phpinfo is great but, in this particular case, it not only gives you tons of useless information, but also omits the majority of information you are looking for. The command above, by its turn, will show you the majority of paths you need, since you know how to use it. For example: it will not inform you where php-cgi is, unless you ask it.

Answer (score 1):

My install is in

```
/etc/php.d/
```

and

```
/usr/include/php
```

But I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: `/usr/include/php` should contain header files only (*.h) while the configuration is present in `/etc/php.d`. Usually, PHP resides in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this command

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```